# Monotone rainbow sequence in the grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Let $[N]:=\{1,\dots,N\}$. For a sequence $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_k,y_k)\in [N]^2$ of points in the grid, we say the sequence is increasing if $x_1<\dots<x_k$ and $y_1<\dots<y_k$. Similarly we say a sequence is decreasing if $x_1<\dots<x_k$ and $y_1>\dots>y_k$.

Let $c$ be a coloring of the grid $[N]^2$ where no color is repeated in any row/column (so that for distinct $(x,y),(x’,y’)$ $c((x,y)) =c((x’,y’))$ implies $x\neq x’$ and $y\neq y’$).

We let $f(c)$ (respectively $g(c)$) be the largest $k$ such that there exists increasing (respectively decreasing) points $p_1,\dots,p_k$ such that $c(p_i)\neq c(p_j)$ for distinct $i,j$. We also define $h(c) = \max\{f(c),g(c)\}$.

Let $F(N)$ (respectively $H(N)$) be the minimum of $f(c)$ (respectively $h(c)$) over all colorings $c$ of $[N]^2$.

Are there any known bounds for $F,H$, has this problem been studied before? I can prove $F(N)\ge \log N$ and $H(N)\ge (1-o(1))\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Does not greedy algorithm (start from the lower left corner and on each, say $s$-th, step add a vertex $p_{s+1}=(x_{s+1},y_{s+1})$ of a still not used color so that $x_{s+1}=x_s+1,y_s<y_{s+1}\leqslant y_{s}+s+1$) prove $\sqrt{N}$ lower bound for $F$?

Comment: ah yes. that does indeed work.

Comment: In fact, @FedorPetrov's method provides about $\sqrt{2N}$, and we may improve it to $2\sqrt N$ by swapping directions: at even steps, put $y_{s+1}=y_s+1$ and choose $x_{s+1}$ greedily.